# Adding a title attribute on the image tag - How to customize article's full image layout?

Tags: joomla-3.x, articles, template-override, layout, images

I want the full image of an article to use the value of an alt attribute in a title attribute, too. I have been searching everywhere and just can't find the correct file.

The file which provides the image to be shown is

```
/components/com_content/views/article/tmpl/default.php
```

When I delete this part:

```
<?php echo JLayoutHelper::render('joomla.content.full_image', $this->item); ?>
```

The image doesn't get rendered anymore.

Where can I edit the HTML of it, so I can copy&paste the variable which is used for the img alt attribute into the title attribute?

Answer (score 1):

The file you are looking for is located in:

```
[ROOT_DIRECTORY]/layouts/joomla/content/full_image.php
```

To create an override for it, copy it and place it inside:

```
[ROOT_DIRECTORY]/templates/YOUR_TEMPLATE/html/layouts/joomla/content/full_image.php
```

There you can modify it as you like.

To learn more on layouts and overrides read here:

- **[Joomla Layout Overrides](https://docs.joomla.org/Layout_Overrides_in_Joomla)**